# simple, exasperating d3.js example

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am entering d3.js at ground level. There's a steep learning curve ahead of me, I know, but I didn't quite expect to get stuck on the second simple tutorial I tried. Now's the change to make the maximal marginal contribution to a fellow programmer's understanding!

I'm trying to get a simple svg bar chart to work using my data, which is virtually identical to the sample.

**Bostock's data**

```
name    value
Locke   4
Reyes   8
Ford    15
Jarrah  16
Shephard    23
Kwon    42
```

**My data**

```
year    value 
year2013    2476
year2014    7215
year2015    23633
year2016thru229 21752
```

Note that our second columns have the same name. Both contain numbers. I gave my dataset the same name he did. Thus I should be able to run his code (below) without changing a thing, but it returns this:

```
Unexpected value NaN parsing width attribute.

...uments);null==e?this.removeAttribute(n):this.setAttribute(n,e)}function 

d3.min.js (line 1, col 2575)

Unexpected value NaN parsing x attribute.

...uments);null==e?this.removeAttribute(n):this.setAttribute(n,e)}function 

d3.min.js (line 1, col 2575)
```

His code as well as the tutorial are [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7341714).

Comment: While Eric's answer is a valid one, I'm still curious about why your TSV didn't work. Did you put a tab stop between each field, and a carriage return after each row?

Comment: I suspect it was an issue with the directory, not the file itself, which I downloaded straight from Drive (and which really did have the same column names as Bostock's, despite what I typed up there). To clarify: when I type an abbreviated file path into the script src tag, it will direct automatically to a .js file in the same folder as my index.html — right? What about if I'm hosting the files online?

Comment: I didn't understand your question: are you talking about the script itself (inside script tag) or about the CSV or TSV you load? If you are talking about the CSV or TSV, I believe they have to be in the same domain, because of the same-origin policy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 1):

You're not feeding D3 your data in the correct format.

https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/kdcLj5jj/1/

```
var data = [
{year:'year2013',value:2476},
{year:'year2014',value:7215},
{year:'year2015',value:23633},
{year:'year2016thru229',value:21752}
]

var width = 420,
    barHeight = 20;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width);

  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  chart.attr("height", barHeight * data.length);

  var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

  bar.append("rect")
      .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
      .attr("height", barHeight - 1);

  bar.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value) - 3; })
      .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.value; });


function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value; // coerce to number
  return d;
}
```